# How to install the gviz_api library?

Tags: django, google-visualization

I'm using Django to create a website with the gcharts library but I'm getting the error:

```
ImportError: You must install the gviz_api library.
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Well, if you need help, you should specify exactly what problem you are having and what you have tried. "My problem is installing the library" is not helpful and will attract close votes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can load from source from https://github.com/google/google-visualization-python and run "setup.py", or:

```
pip install -U https://github.com/google/google-visualization-python/zipball/master
```

Comment: I tried this and I get this error: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-jyhhyld4-build/